onResume is not called when I finish another Activity
When I execute the following and return to the MainActivity.kt through finish(), the onResume method is not called there, why?
ActivityForGPSPermission.kt
class ActivityForGPSPermission : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_for_gps)

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.tryAgain)
        .setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }
     }
}

MainActivity.kt
override fun onResume() {
 super.onResume()
 ...
}


are you sure that when you call finish() you get to MainActivity?

I just have only two Activities. MainActivity and  ActivityForGPSPermission

How are you launching the permission activity? How do you know onResume is not called?

By setting a break point in it and also displaying a log

It is hard to answer your question because it should be called regarding the activity lifecycle.
As a workaround solution you can try to use startActivityForResult().
Just launch ActivityForGPSPermission and handle the result in MainActivity and do what you need.
You can find examples and more explanation by this link
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result
